# Pourquoi a-t-on utilisé le présent du conditionel du verbe détecter dans le texte ci-dessous ?

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison, conditionnel

Avant le progrès de Deep Learning, la quasi-totalité des méthodes pour la détection d'objets était effectuée à l'aide de techniques d'apprentissage automatique classiques. Les plus courants comprenaient la technique de détection d'objets viola-jones, les transformées de caractéristiques invariantes à l'échelle (SIFT) et l'histogramme des gradients orientés (HOG).

Ceux-ci détecteraient un certain nombre de caractéristiques communes à travers l'image et classeraient leurs clusters à l'aide d'une régression logistique, d'histogrammes de couleurs ou de Random Forest.

Comment: D'où est tiré ce texte ou qui l'a écrit ? Il faut le préciser. Je ne connais rien au sujet je préfère ne pas corriger. Il semble que *les plus courants* réfèrent à *techniques d'apprentissage* donc un nom féminin, si c'est bien ça il faut écrire *courantes*. Une recherche sur internet me renvoie à la méthode de Viola et Jones, ce sont des noms propres et il y a des majuscules (Viola et Jones en français, Viola-Jones en anglais) je ne l'ai pas trouvé en un seul mot.  Tu peux corriger en cliquant sur *edit*.

Comment: Bonjour, ce texte est tiré d'un cours PDF sur la vision par ordinateur.

Comment: @LouardiBrahim il faudrait beaucoup plus de contexte (langue maternelle de l'auteur du texte, etc.) pour répondre précisément. Une explication plausible est une mauvaise traduction du "would" passé en anglais : "ceux-ci détectaient ... classaient ..." (avant l'arrivée du deep learning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Les verbes *détecteraient* et *classeraient* sont au conditionnel parce que la personne qui a écrit le texte n'est pas certaine que « ceux-ci » (en l'état du texte je pense que *ceux-ci* réfère à "la technique de détection d'objets "violajones", les transformées de caractéristiques invariantes à l'échelle (SIFT) et l'histogramme des gradients orientés (HOG)") font effectivement ce qu'elle écrit. Elle le sait parce qu'elle l'a entendu dire ou lu mais ne l'a pas vérifié elle-même.

Comment: Bonjour le mot violajones est le nom d'un méthode de détection d'objets.  https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9thode_de_Viola_et_Jones#:~:text=La%20m%C3%A9thode%20de%20Viola%20et,des%20objets%20dans%20une%20image

Comment: Ce texte est tiré du cours pdf de mon professeur, Il est professeur d’université mais sa langue maternelle n’est pas le français

Comment: Je pense qu’il a écrit voilajones au lieu de voila-Jones par erreur

Comment: ok dans le pdf c'est écrit "viola-jones" mais quand je l'ai copié et collé dans le corps de la question il a été modifié, et je n'y ai pas fait attention désolé

Comment: D'accord. Sans majuscules ? Et peux-tu regarder si c'est écrit *courant* ou *courantes* (féminin)? J'enlève mes commentaires....

Comment: Oui, dans le PDF, c'est sans majuscules. C'est écrit "courants"

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer but too long for a comment. The original sentence has many flaws that show it wasn't written by a native French speaker.

> Avant le progrès de Deep Learning, la quasi-totalité des méthodes pour la détection d'objets était effectuée à l'aide de techniques d'apprentissage automatique classiques. Les plus courants comprenaient la technique de détection d'objets viola-jones, les transformées de caractéristiques invariantes à l'échelle (SIFT) et l'histogramme des gradients orientés (HOG).

Here is one way to rewrite it :

> Avant les avancées du Deep Learning, la quasi-totalité des méthodes de détection d'objets s'appuyait sur des techniques d'apprentissage automatique classiques. Les plus courantes incluaient la méthode de Viola et Jones, la transformation de caractéristiques visuelles invariante à l'échelle (SIFT) et l'histogramme de gradient orienté (HOG).